# Xamarin PCL Rendering

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, cross-platform

I am new to Android,C# and Xamarin, I have just started learning about custom renderers and I would like to try implementing some.

I would like to achieve custom image rendering at the end but do not know where to start.

For example how do i know what functions I can overwrite and also how the PCL in xamarin actually reads in XAML image source and how it processes it(how the data flow from xaml to image being rendered, what functions are being called)?

Comment: Have you tried implementing some code? Can you share that?

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to achieve custom image rendering at the end but do not know **where to start**.

Xamarin has a pretty good [documentation about Custom Renderers](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/) which contains a step-by-step tutorial and many examples.

> For example how do i know **what functions I can overwrite** and also **how the PCL in xamarin actually reads in XAML image source and how it processes it**

You can take a look at the Xamarin code over at GitHub: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms